# Android Sound not playing in splash screen

Tags: java, android, audio

Im having troubles with playing sound while the splash screen shows. Ive created the "raw" directory under "res" directory and put the droid.mp3 file there (around 150Kb).

This is the code of the java file responsible for the appearance and sound of the splash screen:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity 
{
    public  MediaPlayer splashSound;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(splashBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, R.raw.droid);
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try 
                {
                    sleep(5000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException IE)
                {
                    IE.printStackTrace();
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    Intent mainActivityIntent=new Intent("com.example.stamapp.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        splashSound.release();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To just play sounds you really should use `SoundPool` in favor of `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. To my understanding, it is better to use `MediaPlayer` when playing sounds longer than 5 seconds. Any truth in that, or it doesnt really matters?

Comment: no, that is right! One has to differenciate between "sound", "music" and "audible". I thought by writing "sound" the `< 5 sec` condition was fulfilled.

Comment: well, the length of the mp3 file is 8 seconds, does that make it "audible" ?

Comment: That is hard to say. It really depends on the file itself whether to use SoundPool or MediaPlayer. I've experimented a lot with audio file durations and (5-10) seconds always is critical.

Comment: Why aren't you calling `splashSound.start()` anywhere? Is it just not in the pasted code? `create()` doesn't start the sound playing, `start()` does.

Comment: exactly! that was the deal! forgot to add this line, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of Thread try is using [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) as:

```
 Handler handler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(splashBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        handler = new Handler();  
        splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, 
                                            R.raw.droid);   
        splashSound.start();  //<<<play sound on Splash Screen
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     //start your Next Activity here
   }
};
```

and second way is add [MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) to MediaPlayer instance which invoke when playback of a media source has completed without putting `5000` Delay as :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) 
        {
            super.onCreate(splashBundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this, 
                                                R.raw.droid);   
            splashSound.setOnCompletionListener(new 
                              MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
           @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer splashSound) {

             splashSound.stop();
             splashSound.release();
                   //start your Next Activity here
           }
        });
        splashSound.start();  //<<<play sound on Splash Screen
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the much elaborated answer! but to be honest, i feel pretty stupid right now. i added `splashSound.start();` just before the `sleep(5000);` and changed `splashSound.release();` to `splashSound.stop()` and it worked. i will test my code with your answers to see how it goes. thanks again.

Comment: @AlexTal : must try `setOnCompletionListener` option because this will work without any extra Thread or Handler

Comment: This second version you have here works great and it is very little code!  Thanks