# cant get sound to play on android splash screen (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

i am trying to get a sound file to play when my splash screen is showing on my android app.... i have been trying to figure it out for a few hours now..... when i run my app it just skips the splash sreen all together now

here is my SplashScreen.java

```
package com.skapaidbeats.app.skapaidbeats;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.skapaidbeats.app.skapaidbeats.MainActivity;
import com.skapaidbeats.app.skapaidbeats.R;
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

MediaPlayer music;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                music= MediaPlayer.create(SplashScreen.this, R.raw.sound);
                music.start();
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    music.release();
    finish();
} 
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
package="com.skapaidbeats.app.skapaidbeats">



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/icon_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />


</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your app is working. Just try by printing logs. Or check logcat for any exceptions. Also check whether the music file is there in raw folder.Since the duration is only 3 seconds, splash screen immediately closes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your activity in the manifest?

If you did, this question was asked before, try the following:

[Android Sound not playing in splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314740/android-sound-not-playing-in-splash-screen)

[How to play audio in splash screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370211/how-to-play-audio-in-splash-screen-in-android)

Comment: my manifest has the following activity for the splash screen

             <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/icon_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Can you add your logcat output?

Comment: 03-21 03:32:38.102 10691-10691/com.skapaidbeats.app.skapaidbeats E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1

Comment: i get that error over and over again like 100 times

Comment: i just added my AndroidManifest.Xml to the original question posted above.. you can see it there now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource("/sdcard/audiotrack.mp3");
player.prepare();
player.start();
```